# how to delete consecutive chars and avoid some string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi I'm wondering how I can remove all repeated chars in a url but keept the http:// and query string intact.

example url:

```
https://domain.com:800///some/here..jpg
```

currently have this code wich remove repeated chars:

```
preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9-_\s])\\1+/', '$1', urldecode($url))
```

and resolves to:

```
https:/domain.com:800/some/here.jpg <-- removed the / from https://
```

How I can allow replacing only the path and keept the rest intact?

Comment: what about solving the original problem? How come the dots are duplicated to begin with?

Comment: I need to load some files based on the url scheme then redirect to the "clean" url.

Comment: You can just do it in two steps. Separate string from `http://` first, then `preg_replace`, then join.

Comment: You can use a negative assertion `(?<!https:)`, or just the `:`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good with regex so I can give you an alternative solution without modifying your code:

```
$url = "https://domain.com:800///some/here..jpg";
$url_without_https = substr($url, 8); //assuming its always https://
$urlModified = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9-_\s])\\1+/', '$1', urldecode($url_without_http));
$url = "http://" . $urlModified;
```